# Use Case Diagram UML

Tags: uml

```
UML Use Case Diagram Questions?
If for an appointment system, an actor (patient) can register on the
appointment system, and register process managed by an actor (Doctor).
```

For drawing USE CASE diagram, should I draw a association between doctor and use case (register)? I do not think so, because the doctor will not do anything to the register?
If so, why?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the actors actually do? Is the doctor directly involved in registering the appointment? Does the patient interact directly with the system, or does he call the doctor, who registers him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the doctor is not directly involved in patient's is registration in the appointment system, then there shouldn't be an association.

However someone needs to put information into the appointment system.

So if the doctor himself adds "available" slots into the system, then it should be modeled as his use case.

So at the end there will be one use case "Patient --> book appointment", and one "Doctor --> create appointment slot".

Answer (score 0):

Actually the doctor is making the appointment on behalf of the patient. So for the use case `Register with system` he is the primary actor. The doctor will likely the patients personal data, but the patient is not involved in this part actively. When you describe the use case you will likely see all the actions be between doctor and system under consideration.

I guess that Peter is correct with his assumption that you need 2 use cases here.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but never too late I guess. You will most likely have to create two use cases; one for the doctor and one for the patient.

Simply describe the actions of the doctor; such as create appointment slots, and anything else you expect him to do. Then describe the actions of the patient on the other use case such as Register/Login/Book Appointment/Manage Appointment.